# I got some issue with input and output in Unix

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to write some names and save them to "name.txt"file and make the list seen on monitor. Luckily, I managed to save those names in "name.txt", but have no idea how to make them seen on monitor...
 Any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 500

int main(void)
{
   int i, fd;
   char nameBuf[MAX_SIZE];

   fd=open("name.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0744);
   if(fd<0)
   {
        perror("An error occured while opening the file");
        exit(1);
   }

   while(1)
   {
        puts("Enter name(end to quit) : ");
        read(0, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf));

        if( !strncmp(nameBuf, "end", 3) )
        {
                printf("end input\n");
                break;
        }
        write(fd, nameBuf, 7);
   }


   printf("for loop begins...\n");
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
        fprintf(stdout, nameBuf);
    }

   puts("Operation completed...");

   close(fd);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to see the contents of `name.txt`? How about `cat name.text` ?

Comment: I'd love to, but what i am trying to do is when i executed it, it should print out the lists just after "end"input.. 
,but thx

Comment: @Bubbleski in the for loop to print output why did you use i<3? and you should read from file not directly printing namebuf.

Comment: @LearningC in fact, i tried to print it out as many times as the number of input. but i don't how... that's why i just put i<3..

Comment: @Bubbleski ok. you can read from file and print the content. i have explained in my answer that i posted. it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the output after "end input" you can change the code

```
while(1)
   {
        puts("Enter name(end to quit) : ");
        read(0, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf));

        if( !strncmp(nameBuf, "end", 3) )
        {
                printf("end input\n");
                break;
        }
        write(fd, nameBuf, 7);
    }

 printf("for loop begins...\n");
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
        fprintf(stdout, nameBuf);
    }
```

To

```
while(1)
   {
        puts("Enter name(end to quit) : ");
        read(0, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf));

        if( !strncmp(nameBuf, "end", 3) )
        {
                printf("end input\n");
                break;
        }
        write(fd, nameBuf, 7);
    }


system("cat name.txt");
```

`system()` will run the `cat` to display the content of `name.txt` after `end` input.
if not using `system()` then you should read from the file and then write to the output. not directly writing the content of `nameBuf`, which will be the last read input not the full file content. so you read from file and then write to display.
You can read from the file using this code,

```
while ((read(fd, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf))) > 0)
{
    write(1, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and concern. hope i can get your help next time too.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code helps. Comments are inserted wherever needed.

```
int main(void)
{
   int i, fd;
   char nameBuf[MAX_SIZE];

   fd=open("name.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0744);
   if(fd<0)
   {
        perror("An error occured while opening the file");
        exit(1);
   }

   while(1)
   {
        puts("Enter name(end to quit) : ");
        int bytesRead = read(0, nameBuf, sizeof(nameBuf)); //bytesRead variable to know the num of bytes read into nameBuf

        if( !strncmp(nameBuf, "end", 3) )
        {
                printf("end input\n");
                break;
        }
        write(fd, nameBuf,bytesRead); // write bytes read to fd
   }

   FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
   rewind(fp); // to go back to start of file, so that you can read entire file

 //  close(fd); ---> second option close fd and again open so that file pointer goes to start of file 
 //  fd=open("name.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0744);
   printf("FILE Contents are as follows\n");

   while(read(fd,nameBuf,sizeof(nameBuf)) > 0)
   {
        fprintf(stdout, nameBuf); // or use write    
   }

   puts("Operation completed...");

   close(fd);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I never come up with using FILE structure. Your code gives me a lot. Mucho gracias!!

Comment: You can even use fscanf and fprintf using FILE pointer and I feel this is an easier method to read/ write a file. @Bubbleski

Comment: Since i've just started to learn C in depth, Everything is quite new to me. But i'll try that later. I do appreciate for your concern. @vishram0709